jacocoTestReport compiles my code again. How to avoid?
I am running my tests using ./gradlew test
This compiles and tests my code, I expect jacoco to instument and generate .exec files after this command itself. But when I check no html report are generated.
I believe this to be expected behaviour so I run ./gradlew jacocoTestReport
This executes the code inside my jacocoTestReport, and generates the html coverage report as expected. But why does my code compile again on this step? Seems jacocoTestReport has a dependency on gradle compile task. Is there a way to avoid compiling again?
